# How to debug React Native error with no error stack

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, debugging, react-native-ios

Since I upgraded to Xcode 12 my **release** builds are crashing on iOS for both the simulator and on devices. The problem is that there is **no error stack** and the error is not giving me a hint where to start. When running in debug there are no errors shown.

I assume there is some version mismatch for a dependency or an issue with the js bundling.

Did anyone encounter the same error or knows how to debug release builds? I would highly appreciate help.

```
Running application <REDACTED> ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2020-11-25 18:38:00.767418+0100 EASY[37489:403160] [native] Unhandled JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

no stack
2020-11-25 18:38:00.771458+0100 EASY[37489:403160] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

no stack', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

no stack'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b2dbaf2 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b130e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   EASY                                0x00000001044d0182 RCTFormatError + 0
    3   EASY                                0x00000001044e7267 __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke + 677
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f0e27ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f0e39c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f0f1e75 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1152
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b249dab __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b24462e __CFRunLoopRun + 2685
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b2436c6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001106e2db3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000119b3a187 -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000119b3f038 UIApplicationMain + 101
    13  EASY                                0x000000010433a436 main + 80
    14  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f172409 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

no stack', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

no stack'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.0.2 - Device: iPhone 11 (F7A041B8-8C3F-4F6C-86FA-D11C8F1B5571) - Runtime: iOS 14.2 (18B79)
```

I am on Xcode 12.2 with RN 0.63.3

Comment: If there isn't any error then from where you get the above one?

Comment: you might get better info if you set a breakpoint on exceptions (when thrown)

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar sorry but your question is counter productive. The output comes from Xcode

Comment: @mr.fixit to you know how to set those in RN? My Editor is IntelliJ

Comment: I do! And so will you, after reading http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: Ok but this is how to debug native code. The error states this is an JS error. And most importantly the issue still does only exist in production builds